# Migrating inline assmbly code to cpp

Tags: assembly, stack

```
int* ptr;
int* begin;

while (ptr > begin) {
    int val = *(--ptr);
    __asm push val
}
```

this is the portion of code i want to migrate.

In this project

ptr points to a memory location say x
begin points to a memory location which is 16 bytes above x 
so i have have slot of 16 byte memory and nothing is stored in this memory location.

I have to migrate this particular portion to c++.

I don't know why this portion of code is there in this project as i am new to it. But the logic wont work without it.

Can anyone help.

Comment: non of those answers are working

Comment: That's a pity, but it's still a duplicate. I'll have a look at your previous question.